# Using pandas, find the intersecting regions between two DataFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas Dataframes, using python3.x:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {0:['chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr2'], 
    1:[1, 100, 150, 900, 1], 2:[100, 200, 500, 950, 100], 
    3:['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature4'], 
    4:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 5:['+','+','-','+','+']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

print(df1)

##       0    1    2         3  4  5
## 0  chr1    1  100  feature1  0  +
## 1  chr1  100  200  feature2  0  +
## 2  chr1  150  500  feature3  0  -
## 3  chr1  900  950  feature4  0  +
## 4  chr2    1  100  feature4  0  +

dict2 = {0:['chr1','chr1'], 1:[155, 800], 2:[200, 901], 
    3:['feature5', 'feature6'], 4:[0, 0], 5:['-','+']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
print(df2)
##       0    1    2         3  4  5
## 0  chr1  155  200  feature5  0  -
## 1  chr1  800  901  feature6  0  +
```

The columns to focus on in these dataframes are the first three columns: location, start, and end. Each start:end value represents a distance on location (e.g. `chr1`, `chr2`, `chr3`).

I would like to output the intersection of `df1` against `df2`. Here is the correct output:

```
chr1    155 200 feature2    0   +
chr1    155 200 feature3    0   -
chr1    900 901 feature4    0   +
```

**Explanation:** We find the intersection of `df1` against `df2`. So, `feature2` and `feature3` intersect `df2` at 155 to 200. `feature4` overlaps `df2` at 900 to 901.

What is the most efficient (in terms of runtime and RAM) to find the intersections?

EDIT: There is a Python package which does something similar here: https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/intersections.html

Comment: You want to return the features from your first GFF that also overlap with features from your second GFF, and subset the location to only what's in your second GFF?

Comment: @CJR Yes, that's correct. Currently, the first "small step" in my mind is to ignore the features, and make sure I have the overlapping intervals correct.

Comment: So if one of the a. df2.start == df1.start or b. df2.end == df2.end, you should keep that row? It's not very clear what location, start and end are in this case. I think for simplicity sake, you should refer to the columns by their column names in your dataframe.

Comment: @LiamShalon Yes, though note it's not the rows I am keeping---it's the overlapping position. `chr1    900 901 feature4    0   +` isn't an existing row (this might be clear)

Comment: @EB2127 it is unclear to me what constitutes that something should be included in your intersection dataframe

Comment: @LiamShalon https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/intersections.html

Comment: @LiamShalon I edited the question as well. The motivation is to find the intersection of df1 against df2. So, `feature2` and `feature3` intersect `df2` at 155 to 200. `feature4` overlaps `df2` at 900 to 901. Does this make sense?

Comment: @EB2127 not quite. I'm still not sure what you mean by feature2 and feature3... do you mean columns 2 and 3? Also, where in df1 is there 155? where in df1 is there 901? Please consider adding a graphic to explain what sort of logic you want.

Comment: @LiamShalon Columns 1 and 2 represent a distance, start:end. Think of these are integer intervals. The overlap between [800, 901] and [900, 950] is [900, 901].

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({0:['chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr2'],
    1:[1, 100, 150, 900, 1], 2:[100, 200, 500, 950, 100],
    3:['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature4'],
    4:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 5:['+','+','-','+','+']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:['chr1','chr1'], 1:[155, 800], 2:[200, 901],
    3:['feature5', 'feature6'], 4:[0, 0], 5:['-','+']})
```

You can use `apply` and some logical tests to find overlaps. You'll have to loop over groups for the chromosomes though. You should be able to do something similar for finding and fixing the starts and stops that require adjustment. If I get time later I'll write something for it.

```
new_dfs = []

for chr_name, chr_df in df1.groupby(0):
    chr_df2 = df2.loc[df2[0] == chr_name]
    overlapping = (chr_df[1].apply(lambda x: chr_df2[2] >= x) & chr_df[2].apply(lambda x: chr_df2[1] <= x)).any(axis=1)
    new_dfs.append(chr_df.loc[overlapping, :])

new_dfs = pd.concat(new_dfs)
```

Overall this will be memory efficient, but not super fast. You'd have to probably write something complicated for indexing if you wanted fast.

Comment: I noticed this doesn't quite give the right answer. It outputs

```1  chr1  100  200  feature2  0  +
2  chr1  150  500  feature3  0  -
3  chr1  900  950  feature4  0  +```

Comment: Yeah, this only finds overlaps. The next part is much harder because there are a ton of edge conditions (what do you do if a feature in A overlaps 2 features in B, etc).

Comment: This is a better solution that the approach above. intersection = pd.merge(df1[[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]], df2[[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]], how='inner')

Comment: If you just do an inner join, how well does it work when the feature start and stop are not the same, and feature names are different?